# Exit a loop on press of key and calling another procedure assigned to the key

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a loop which need to be stopped on press of "Right" click on the keyboard and after that a procedure should get called assigned to the "Right" key.

Right now, the loop continues to run even after clicking on the Right key.

I've assigned the procedure to right key using following code:

```
Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "procRight"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Akshat

Answer (score 0):

you need to use another Thread. VBA don't have multiThreading support -  while the loop is running you cant raise any other event parallel to the current code executing. you will need to use other programming language that supports multithreading (like vb.net) in order to perform such task. in general the acceptable way to perform a task like that is to run a while loop (on the main thread) that running as long as a boolean variable is set to true and when the user presses a key that has event handler listener in another thread it will change this boolean variable to false= call another sub and exit for example. please note that multiThreading is advanced topic in programming.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan is entirely right in that the ideal would be to use multi-threading for this task and VBA doesn't have that capability. So first off, you might want to examine your programme structure to devise a better method.

However, VBA can multi-task so there is a workaround if you must achieve this specific task. It requires using `DoEvents` which does have some problems associated with it (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/118468). You won't be able to call a new procedure in your loop, so your `Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "procRight"` will need to be cancelled (do it like this: `Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}"`).

Because `DoEvents` passes control to the operating system, the Application's events will still be fired and can be captured even while your loop is running. What you can do is set a 'Stop' flag in one of your worksheet objects, capture the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event and if the selection is one cell to the right of its previous then the right key must have been pressed (unfortunately, the same would apply if you mouse clicked one cell to the right and therefore wouldn't actually be a RIGHT keystroke, but we're talking a workaround here where nothing's perfect), so you can set the 'Stop' flag. You could then test that flag on each iteration of your loop.

The code would look something like this:

In your Worksheet...

```
Private mRight As Boolean
Private mOldSelection As Range
Public Property Get Right() As Boolean
    Right = mRight
End Property
Public Property Let Right(bool As Boolean)
    mRight = bool
    Me.Activate
    Set mOldSelection = Selection.Cells(Selection.Cells.Count)
End Property
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not mOldSelection Is Nothing Then
        If mOldSelection.Column > 1 Then
            If Target.Cells(1).Address = OldSelection.Offset(, 1).Address Then
                mRight = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set mOldSelection = Target.Cells(Target.Cells.Count)
End Sub
```

And here's an example of a stopped loop in your module...

```
Dim i As Long

Sheet1.Right = False
For i = 1 To 1000000
    DoEvents
    If Sheet1.Right Then
        MsgBox "Stopped"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
MsgBox "Done"
```